# How can I add a multiple / in my link without my styles not working?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, body-parser

I am building a website, and am trying to make it where the links aren't always just`/blog` or `/post1`. I want to get to my posts, but i cant make it where the link is like this `/blog/post`, but when i do that the html shows up, but not the styles. My `style.css` is in the public folder, but its not working. I am using express, body-parser, and node js.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/blog/post1', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../posts/post1.pug');
});
```

When I import the css, I get this error in chrome:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:7000/blog/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Imported css:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
```

It works just fine when I put the link like this `/blog-post1` but not like this `/blog/post1`

It is for some reason saying that the styles are in another location, but why?

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Would you need to import your styles in the main app.js ?

Comment: I imported them, but nothing shows up.

Comment: I mean the css doesnt work, it isnt connecting.

Comment: can you update your question to include the code that retrieves the css please.